# Prove that $span(u, v, w) = span(u+v+w, w-u, 2w)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u, v, w$ be real numbers. Prove that $span (u, v, w) = span (u + v + w, w - u, 2w)$

Hey guys. I've been struggling with this question for a while now. 
I believe I'm supposed to use linear independence to prove this, however I don't believe any of my solutions have made sense.

Things I've tried have included proving linear independence of the span on the right-hand side, followed by setting the linear combination ($a(u) + b(v) + c(w) = x(u+v+w) + y(w - u) + z(2w)$ equal to one another. However any progress I made with this made no sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Note that proving linear independency of the right hand side is not the way to proceed, since you have not information on the linear dependency of $u,v,w$. Proving two sets to be equal can be done by showing that both sets contain each other (as Chappers did in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the latter is contained in the former, since it is a linear combination of elements of the former. For containment the other way, we can essentially invert the transformation:
$$ \begin{align}
u &= -(w-u)-\tfrac{1}{2}(2w), \\
v &= (u+v+w)+(w-u)-(2w), \\
w &= \tfrac{1}{2}(2w).
\end{align} $$
So any vector in the former can be written as a linear combination of vectors in the latter.

Since we have containment in both directions, we must have equality.